# AJAX can't save request to database because of double quotes

Tags: html, ajax, forms

I'm trying to add something to my database that contains double quotes via AJAX, but the problem is that when I'm using double quotes, I can't submit the request with success. How can I find in a string from an HTML form the double quotes, and replace it with 2 quotes? Here it's my form:

```
    <form id='question-frm'>
                    <div class ="modal-body">
                        <div id="msg"></div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Question</label>
                            <input type="hidden" name="qid" value="<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="id" />
                            <textarea rows='3' name="question" required="required" class="form-control" ></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button  class="btn btn-primary" name="save"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> Save</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

And here's my AJAX call:

```
$('#question-frm').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#question-frm [name="submit"]').attr('disabled',true)
        $('#question-frm [name="submit"]').html('Saving...')
        $('#msg').html('')

        $.ajax({
            url:'./save_question.php',
            method:'POST',
            data:$(this).serialize(),
            error:err=>{
                console.log(err)
                alert('An error occured')
                $('#quiz-frm [name="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled')
                $('#quiz-frm [name="submit"]').html('Save')
            },
            success:function(resp){
                    if(resp == 1){
                        alert('Data successfully saved');
                        location.reload()
                    }
            }
        })
    })
```

When I'm submitting the form in the console all I get it's: ,,XHR finished loading: POST """

save_question contains the code:

```
extract($_POST);

if(empty($id)){
    $last_order = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM questions where qid = $qid order by order_by desc limit 1")->fetch_array()['order_by'];
    $order_by = $last_order > 0 ? $last_order + 1 : 0;
    $data = 'question = "'.$question.'" ';
    $data .= ', order_by = "'.$order_by.'" ';
    $data .= ', qid = "'.$qid.'" ';
    $insert_question = $conn->query("INSERT INTO questions set ".$data);
    if($insert_question){
        $question_id = $conn->insert_id;
        $insert = array();
        for($i = 0 ; $i < count($question_opt);$i++){
            $is_right = isset($is_right[$i]) ? $is_right[$i] : 0;
            $insert[] = $conn->query("INSERT INTO question_opt set question_id = $question_id, option_txt = '".$question_opt[$i]."',`is_right` = $is_right ");
        }
        if(count($insert) == 4){
            echo 1;
        }else{
            $delete = $conn->query("DELETE FROM questions where id =".$question_id);
            $delete2 = $conn->query("DELETE FROM question_opt where question_id =".$question_id);
            echo 2;
            
        }

        }
    }else{

        $data = 'question = "'.$question.'" ';
        $data .= ', qid = "'.$qid.'" ';
        $update = $conn->query("UPDATE questions set ".$data." where id = ".$id);
        if($update){
            $delete= $conn->query("DELETE FROM question_opt where question_id =".$id);
            $insert = array();
            for($i = 0 ; $i < count($question_opt);$i++){
                $answer = isset($is_right[$i]) ? 1 : 0;
                $insert[] = $conn->query("INSERT INTO question_opt set question_id = $id, option_txt = '".$question_opt[$i]."',`is_right` = $answer ");
                // echo "INSERT INTO question_opt set question_id = $id, option_txt = '".$question_opt[$i]."',`is_right` = $answer <br>";
            }
            if(count($insert) == 4){
                echo 1;
            }else{
                $delete = $conn->query("DELETE FROM questions where id =".$id);
                $delete2 = $conn->query("DELETE FROM question_opt where question_id =".$id);
                echo 2;
                
            }

            }
    }
```

Comment: If the error occurs in your sql part, you should sanitize your input in the backend. Otherwise your website will be vulnerable to sql injections.

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS) User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: DO NOT USE EXTRACT ON $_POST! It is possibly the easiest way for a user to simply overwrite your code and can lead to oh so many an exploit: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Answer (score -1):

try to change the use:

```
            $("#quiz-frm [name='submit']").removeAttr('disabled')
```

Comment: Didn't helped me...

Comment: then, I dont understand your problem.